# I get stack overflow error in my flutter application

Tags: flutter, stack-overflow

1. I tried to pass data by using  provider between different widget but I got error stack over flow and the code seems nice?.

   ```
    '''

    Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: items.itemsProvide.length,
                  itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => CartItemsDw(
                      items.itemsProvide.values.toList()[i].id,
                      items.itemsProvide.values.toList()[i].title,
                      items.itemsProvide.values.toList()[i].price,
                      items.itemsProvide.values.toList()[i].quatity),
                ),
              )

   '''
   ```
2. I try to pass my data to another widget which are below there and when try to access the data for this widget the error appear

   '''

   ```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    class CartItemsDw extends StatelessWidget {
      final String id;
      final String title;
      final double price;
      final int quantity;
      CartItemsDw( this.id,this.title,this.price, this.quantity);
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Card(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10,vertical: 4),
          child: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: ListTile(leading: CircleAvatar(child: Text('\$$price'),),
          title: Text(title),
          subtitle: Text('total \$${(price*quantity)}'),
          trailing: Text('\$$quantity x'),
          ),  
         ),
        );
      }
    }


   '''
   ```

Comment: what error did you get excatly

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind, Listview.builder is auto expandable and scrollable.
Just remove Expanded wrapping from outside the list.

```
 ListView.builder(
               itemCount: items.itemsProvide.length,
               itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => CartItemsDw(
                   items.itemsProvide.values.toList()[i].id,
                   items.itemsProvide.values.toList()[i].title,
                   items.itemsProvide.values.toList()[i].price,
                   items.itemsProvide.values.toList()[i].quatity),
             );
```

Comment: thanks! happy coing. You may tik asnwer as accepted! if anyone faces same problem, he will have get the help from the above answer.